# Quantifiers bind tightly?

Tags: notation, quantifiers

Is this true that it is a commonly agreed rule that $\forall x\in A:P(x) \wedge Q$ and $\forall x\in A:P(x) \Rightarrow Q$ should be interpreted correspondingly as $(\forall x\in A:P(x)) \wedge Q$ and $(\forall x\in A:P(x)) \Rightarrow Q$?

The question is about implied parentheses. Are the other interpretations $\forall x\in A:(P(x) \wedge Q)$ and $\forall x\in A:(P(x) \Rightarrow Q)$ common?

Comment: I would read this as $\forall x \in A : (P(x) \wedge Q)$. But one should add parentheses wherever there's ambiguity (e.g., here.)

Comment: I would have said that in the absence of any parentheses, quantifiers always extend as far as possible to the right, agreeing with Mike Miller's reading.

Comment: @MJD Exactly the opposite happens. The convention is that if there are no parentheses, then the scope of the quantifier is only the closest predicate.

Comment: The rule is that there is no rule that can be counted on.

Comment: @GitGud Cite please?

Comment: @MJD [Language, Proof and Logic](http://ssdi.di.fct.unl.pt/~pb/cadeiras/lc/0102/lpl%20textbook.pdf) doesn't specify this, I think. But it is assumed so. You can convince yourself of this by looking at the exercises in page 315 of the book (page 325 of the linked PDF). The statements are only true if the scope is the closest quantifier. A different source is [here](http://dingo.sbs.arizona.edu/~hammond/ling178-sp06/mathCh5.pdf). The scope is the closest quantifier by definition of well formed formula on page 2 of the PDF (page 78 in the book).

Comment: @MJD More pictorial examples of this convention can be found on these links which I found with a google search: [1](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/content/logic/pred_logic/quantification/quantification.html) and [2](http://logic.philosophy.ox.ac.uk/tutorial4/Tut4-03.htm). I think except for one time, I've always seen the quantifier binding only the closest predicate. That one time it required parentheses every time, without them the formula in the question wouldn't even be well formed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it is customary to "bind variables tightly" is to ensure we have clarity regarding the *scope* of a quantified variable. Absent any parentheses, the tightest of bounds applies.

To omit parentheses is sloppy, at best, but it happens (to the misfortune of those who have to mind-read with respect to the author's intention).